# Different Unicode strings encode the same

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, encoding, utf-8

I have two unicode strings that even after normalization are different. However when encoded to UTF-8 they are the same. I'd like to understand how (and perhaps why) they are different.

They are both identifiers for entities and the lookup fails because the identifier is wrong, however as byte strings they are the same so I'd like to understand how it is possible that we arrived at different unicode strings (they've been processed by different subsystems) and how I could tell that they are in fact the same.

`"\u8a92\u6089\u5bfd\u4267\ucdb7\u5727\u4039\U0002ae18\U00025314\u30c3"`

and:

`"\u8a92\u6089\u5bfd\u4267\ucdb7\u5727\u4039\ud86b\ude18\ud854\udf14\u30c3"`

The issue doesn't appear to be normalization. I realise that elements of this question are unanswerable, but I would appreciate any clues!

```
>>> a = u"\u8a92\u6089\u5bfd\u4267\ucdb7\u5727\u4039\ud86b\ude18\ud854\udf14\u30c3"
>>> b = u"\u8a92\u6089\u5bfd\u4267\ucdb7\u5727\u4039\U0002ae18\U00025314\u30c3"
>>> a == b
False
>>> import unicodedata
>>> unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', a) == unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', b)
False
>>> a.encode('UTF-8') == b.encode('UTF-8')
True
```

Comment: The characters U+D86B and friends are surrogate characters, ie. (phony) codepoints that are used by UTF16 to encode (actual) codepoints above U+FFFF. String `a` has thus not been properly decoded. As @snakecharmerb noted, recent Python versions see this string as broken; however Python 2.7 seems to allow this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you are getting your result.  In Python 2.7, your `a` and `b` Unicode strings are the same:

```
    >>> a = u"\u8a92\u6089\u5bfd\u4267\ucdb7\u5727\u4039\ud86b\ude18\ud854\udf14\u30c3"
    >>> b = u"\u8a92\u6089\u5bfd\u4267\ucdb7\u5727\u4039\U0002ae18\U00025314\u30c3"
    >>> a == b
    True
    >>> a
    u'\u8a92\u6089\u5bfd\u4267\ucdb7\u5727\u4039\U0002ae18\U00025314\u30c3'
    >>> b
    u'\u8a92\u6089\u5bfd\u4267\ucdb7\u5727\u4039\U0002ae18\U00025314\u30c3'
```

Python 2.7 uses UTF-16LE internally to store Unicode strings.  Codepoints above U+FFFF are stored using surrogates (two 16-bit code units).  Note how they display the same even though entered differently.  The two strings are parsed and stored internally the same way.  Another example:

```
>>> s = u'\U00025314'
>>> len(s)
2
>>> hex(ord(s[0]))
'0xd854'
>>> hex(ord(s[1]))
'0xdf14'
>>> s = u'\ud854\udf14'
>>> s
u'\U00025314'
```

In Python 3.3+ the [leaky abstraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaky_abstraction) exposing implementation details of how Unicode is stored internally has been fixed:

```
>>> # python 3.3+
>>> s = '\U00025314'
>>> len(s)
1
>>> hex(ord(s[0]))
>>> hex(ord(s[0]))
'0x25314'
>>> s.encode('utf8')
b'\xf0\xa5\x8c\x94'

>>> s = '\ud854\udf14'
>>> s
'\ud854\udf14'
>>> s.encode('utf8')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't encode characters in position 0-1: surrogates not allowed
```